# Mi carousel no funciona BOOTSTRAP5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

tengo un problema, mi carousel no funciona, estoy trabajando con bootstrap5

```
     <div id="mainSlider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="img/slide01.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="img/slide02.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="img/slide03.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

La primer imagen se renderiza pero el carousel no muestra todas las imagenes

Comment: No añada un link a un repo de GitHub, puede añadir un snippet con el botón de código de la parte superior, en las herramientas de edición, este le abrirá una ventana emergente donde podrá añadir y ejecutar código HTML, CSS y JavaScript. Además, asegúrese de haber vinculado correctamente Bootstrap Bundle JS (al final de la etiqueta body)

Comment: Incluso antes ver lo que sea, lo más probable es que tengas mal el link de bootstrap 5. Por lo que deberías seguir las indicaciones de [bootstrap mismo](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: No, no está mal porque el resto de  cosas que hago con bootstrap lo agarra, todas las clases las reconoce y modifica.

Ya saqué el link del repo!

Gracias

Comment: ¿Has añadido el Bootstrap Bundle: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`?

Comment: Recuerda que estamos hablando del experimental bootstrap, el cual esta en [beta1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/). Y debes revisar si los archivos que ocupas, contienen todo el contenido. [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/contents/#css-files)

Comment: @anythingg, no, por lo que se vee, el ha descargado bootstrap, lo tiene añadido como: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: He ingresado al repo que el OP borró, por lo que se puede ver, no ha añadido el Bootstrap Bundle y esto puede ser causa del malfuncionamiento del carousel.

Comment: Es lo primero que le he dicho, 99% de los casos, son por añadir incorrectamente el bootstrap.

Comment: Ahi bajo Bundle, ese no lo tengo, tengo popper

Comment: tenian razon, faltaba una linea para linkear los JS

Comment: Si no son mentiras lo que decimos acá jaja. Suerte !!